# How to get wordWrap to work in PIXIjs BitmapText

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

**Objective**

We are trying to get wordWrap to work with `PIXIjs (v3)` `PIXI.extras.BitmapText`, but we can't get it to work in the same way that is does for standard Text.

**Desired output:** *[Wrapped text as expected]*

```
var someText = new window.PIXI.Text('blah blah blah',
                {
                    font: '32px Arial',
                    fill: 0x939393,
                    align: 'center',
                    wordWrap: true,
                    wordWrapWidth: me.width * (0.9 / window.devicePixelRatio)
                });
```

**Issue:**  *[Did not wrap text as expected]*

```
var someOtherText = new window.PIXI.BitmapText('blah blah blah',
                {
                    font: 'santana-grey-20',
                    align: 'center',
                    wordWrap: true,
                    wordWrapWidth: me.width * (0.9 / window.devicePixelRatio)
                });
```

Has anyone done this before or have any suggestions as to what to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike PIXI.Text, PIXI BitmapText has no built-in support for word wrapping.

You're only alternative is to split the text into multiple PIXI BitmapTexts.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Why use mutliple BitmapTexts? You can just write \n to get a new line.

Answer (score 2):

In bitmapText, you have to set maxWidth property of style to line break
see [here](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.BitmapText.html)

```
var someOtherText = new window.PIXI.BitmapText('blah blah blah',
                {
                    font: 'santana-grey-20',
                    align: 'center',
                    maxWidth: 200
// The max width of the text before line wrapping.
                });
```